# How to save manually edited msg files?

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

I am trying to save manually edited msg files.

After the user edits the displayed email and saves, the older msg file should be replaced with the edited one.

I tried `CreateItemFromTemplate` to display the mail. I do not know where the edited mail is saved. It does not replace the original file.

```vb
Sub test()
    Dim File As Variant
    Dim count As Integer
    Set mailobj = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    count = 0
    File = Dir(ActiveWorkbook.path & "\Daily\INDIA\ready\")
    While (File <> "")
        If InStr(File, "msg") > 0 Then
            Set xOutMail = mailobj.CreateItemFromTemplate(ActiveWorkbook.path & "\Daily\INDIA\ready\" & File)
            xOutMail.Display
        End If
        File = Dir
    Wend
    Debug.Print count
End Sub
```

I can display the mail. I cannot save it. I cannot replace the original file.

Comment: Don't they go in Draft Folder ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [CreateItemFromTemplate](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/Outlook.Application.CreateItemFromTemplate) method of the Application class creates a new Microsoft Outlook item from an Outlook template (.oft) and returns the new item. The second argument specifies the folder in which the item is to be created. If this argument is omitted, the default folder for the item type will be used (Draft for mail items).

```
Sub CreateFromTemplate2() 
  Dim MyItem As Outlook.MailItem 
  Set MyItem = Application.CreateItemFromTemplate("C:\statusrep.oft", _ 
  Application.Session.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderDrafts)) 
  MyItem.Save 
  ' or
  MyItem.SaveAs Environ("HOMEPATH") & "\My Documents\statusrep.oft", OlSaveAsType.olTemplate 
End Sub
```

If you need to save it as a template you need to use the [SaveAs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.mailitem.saveas) method of the Outlook items. It saves the Microsoft Outlook item to the specified path and in the format of the specified file type. If the file type is not specified, the MSG format (.msg) is used.

Finally, you may find the [How To: Create a new Outlook message based on a template](https://www.add-in-express.com/creating-addins-blog/2011/08/31/outlook-create-message-based-on-template/) article helpful.